# MySQL datediff() function always returning the same result regardless of its value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running the following query but can't seem to get the `datediff()` filter to work. The query is executing successfully but  even if I change the `datediff()` to different values I still get the same result.

```
SELECT project_id
     , google_rank
     , COALESCE(
        ( SELECT google_rank
            FROM eig_ranking mi
           WHERE mi.project_id = m.project_id
           ORDER BY project_id limit 1
                 )
         , 0) - google_rank AS movement
     , keyword
     , domain
  FROM eig_ranking m
 WHERE (DATEDIFF(rank_date, NOW())) / 7 <= 12
   AND google_rank != 0
 ORDER BY movement DESC
```

Comment: the google_rank!=0 filter works fine but not the datediff() filter

Comment: Can you run, `select DATEDIFF(rank_date, NOW()) / 7, count(*) from eig_ranking group by DATEDIFF(rank_date, NOW()) / 7`? My guess would be that you don't have anything more than 12 weeks old in there.

Comment: where exactly do I insert the code for that\

Comment: What is the result that you get?  Are you expecting results but getting none?  Getting the wrong results?   Consider eliminating the DATEDIFF section of your where clause, and instead add it to your select (So SELECT project_id, DATEDIFF(rank_date, NOW())/7 FROM eig_ranking) and see what values you actually get (and are they > or  < 12).

Comment: hey, thanks for your replies. I figured it out. I am not sure if its a MYSQL bug or documentation fault but interchanging the variables in the datediff() function to  DATEDIFF(NOW(), rank_date) makes it work fine for all my queries and the results are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your replies. I figured it out. I am not sure if its a MYSQL bug or documentation fault but interchanging the variables in the datediff() function to DATEDIFF(NOW(), rank_date) makes it work fine for all my queries and the results are all correct